# Regex; moving file based on file name matching folder location

Tags: c#, regex, file, move

I understand how to match file names according to a specific naming pattern with Regex, I would want to move the file to a specific folder in the directory that has matching details from the file name. For example,

```
reportONE14073012300000.xls
```

The general format is:

```
(Filename\YYMMDD\HRS\MM\SS.xls)
```

this file is within a temp location `A:temp` but needs to go to

```
 A:\Report\2014\ONE\July\30\1200\0030
```

The general format is:

```
(A:\Report\2014\ONE\MM\DD\HH\MM)
```

Comment: Where you are struck? also post your current code

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will parse the input text and convert it to expected path.

```
string name = "reportONE14073012300000";
var match = Regex.Match(name, @"(?i)[a-z]+(\d{14})");
if(match.Success)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(match.Groups[1].Value,"yyMMddHHmmssff",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    string path = string.Format(@"A:\Report\{0}\ONE\{1}\{2}\{3}\{4}",
    dt.ToString("yyyy"),
    dt.ToString("MMMM"),
    dt.ToString("dd"),
    dt.ToString("HH00"),
    dt.ToString("mm00"));
    Console.WriteLine(path);// A:\Report\2014\ONE\July\30\1200\0030
}
```

I leave moving the file part to yourself, try it out.

Comment: in the dt.ToString should it not be "YY" "MM" and in the path I give it the path to the directory folder main which would be @A:\report ??? thanks for all the help

Comment: There is no pattern `YY`, `MM` will result in `07` rather than `July`. Yes for path, it is a typo, I'll correct it.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

Comment: Which line throws this exception?

Comment: DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(match.Groups[1].Value,"yyMMddHHmmssff",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Not sure why? It worked for me, also check [ideone sample](http://ideone.com/Qz44D9) it works

Comment: Maybe the input is different and the "filename" contains digits which are matched as part of the date in this code (like `"report999914073012300000"` where `report9999` is the filename and 9999 is parsed as year and month). The OP should most likely replace the part `[a-z]+` with the regex for the filename component and also ensure that the 14 digits parsed as the date/time are located at the end of the string (e.g. by appending a `$` to the regex pattern or checking `match.Length == name.Length`. Checking only `match.Success` will also be true for a partial match which is not desired here.

Comment: the temp folder and the folder to which the file should get moved to are on an FPT; would this change this code?

Comment: I made some of the changes suggested and now to run through the code but no movement of file.                                  string name = "reportONE14073012535800.xls";
            var match = Regex.Match(name, @"(?i)[a-z]+(\d{10})$");
            if (match.Success)
            {
                DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(match.Groups[1].Value, "yyMMddHHmmssff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                string path = string.Format(@"A:\report\one\{0}\{1}\{2}\{3}\{4}",

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do you. It's not tested but, in addition to moving the files about, it should take take carey of parsing out the file names and creating the entire archive directory tree as it goes.

The method `Archive()` returns a bool indicating whether or not the specified file was moved or not.

You might need to tweak the regular expression as it's based on my perhaps incorrect understanding of the file name format.

```
private static void ArchiveAll( DirectoryInfo dropDirectory , DirectoryInfo archiveRoot )
{
  foreach ( FileInfo file in dropDirectory.EnumerateFiles("*.xls") )
  {
    Archive( file , archiveRoot ) ;
  }
}

private static bool Archive( FileInfo file , DirectoryInfo archiveRoot )
{
  bool wasArchived = false ;
  Match m = rxFileNamePattern.Match(file.Name) ;
  if ( m.Success )
  {
    string   pfx   = m.Groups["prefix"].Value ;
    string   sfx   = m.Groups["suffix"].Value ;
    string   dtRaw = m.Groups["timestamp"].Value ;
    DateTime dt    = DateTime.ParseExact( dtRaw , "yyMMddHHmm" , CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ) ;
    string   path  = Path.Combine( "."       ,
                       pfx                   ,
                       dt.ToString( "yyyy" ) ,
                       sfx                   ,
                       dt.ToString( "MMMM" ) ,
                       dt.ToString( "dd"   ) ,
                       dt.ToString( "HH00" ) ,
                       dt.ToString( "00mm" )
                       ) ;
    DirectoryInfo archive = archiveRoot.CreateSubdirectory( path ) ;

    file.MoveTo( Path.Combine( archive.FullName , file.Name ) ) ;
    wasArchived = true ;
  }
  return wasArchived ;
}
const string fnPattern = @"
  ^                       # - start of text, followed by
  (?<prefix> \p{Ll}+) # - prefix    : 1 or more lowercase letters, followed by
  (?<suffix>    \p{Lu}+ ) # - suffix    : 1 or more uppercase letters, followed by
  (?<timestamp> \d{10}  ) # - timestamp : 10 decimal digits in the form YYMMDDhhmm, followed by
  (?<seconds>   \d{4}   ) # - seconds   : 4 decimal digits
  (?<ext>       \.xls   ) # - ext       :  the literal '.xls'
  $                       # - end of text.
  " ;
const RegexOptions fnPatternOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                                    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
                                    | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture
                                    ;
static readonly Regex rxFileNamePattern = new Regex( fnPattern , fnPatternOptions ) ;
```

Comment: I am getting a must declare a body, I have tried to create a source directory but it is not working for me.